# Titanium: Trap android back button

Tags: titanium

I'd like to capture the android back button to force confirmation before exiting the app. My app is a two window/two tab app, based on the skeleton that the titanium cli creates.  I've tried all three approaches below. As far as I can tell, the back button is never trapped, the app just closes when the back button is pressed.

Titanium 3.2.0 CLI
OS X 10.9

```
  // below true of all windows:
  // modal: true,
  // exitOnClose:true
  // android:back and androidback have been tried

Ti.App.addEventListener('androidback', function(e){
    var confirmClear = Titanium.UI.createAlertDialog({


        message:'Exit App?', 
        buttonNames: ['Yes','No']
    });
    confirmClear.show();
    confirmClear.addEventListener('click',function(e) {
        if (e.index === 0) {

         win1.close();

          }
    });
});

//////////////////////////////////////////////////  

win1.addEventListener('androidback', function(e){
    var confirmClear = Titanium.UI.createAlertDialog({


        message:'Exit App?', 
        buttonNames: ['Yes','No']
    });
    confirmClear.show();
    confirmClear.addEventListener('click',function(e) {
        if (e.index === 0) {

         win1.close();

          }
    });
});

//////////////////////////////////////////////////  

win2.addEventListener('androidback', function(e){
    var confirmClear = Titanium.UI.createAlertDialog({

        message:'Exit App?', 
        buttonNames: ['Yes','No']
    });

    confirmClear.show();

    confirmClear.addEventListener('click',function(e) {
        if (e.index === 0) {

         win2.close();

          }
    });
});
```

After reading the suggestions, here's my now working code:

```
tabGroup.addEventListener('androidback', function(e){
    var confirmClear = Titanium.UI.createAlertDialog({


        message:'Exit App?', 
        buttonNames: ['Yes','No']
    });
    confirmClear.show();
    confirmClear.addEventListener('click',function(e) {
        if (e.index === 0) {

         tabGroup.close();


          }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I always use `android:back`.

When you use the tabGroups approach you should be aware that the tabs are linked to soft windows (`win1` and `win2`) and perhaps thats why they don't catch the `android:back` event. 
Saying that, you should catch this event in your tabGroup (ApplicationTabGroup.js). There you should add something like this:

```
function ApplicationTabGroup(Window) {
    //create module instance
    var self = Ti.UI.createTabGroup();
...

    self.addEventListener('android:back', function(e){
        var confirmClear = Titanium.UI.createAlertDialog({
            message:'Exit App?', 
            buttonNames: ['Yes','No']
        });
        confirmClear.show();
        confirmClear.addEventListener('click',function(e) {
            if (e.index === 0) {
                win1.close(); //this line won't work
                //$.index.activeTab = 1; //use this to switch to tab2

            }
        });
    });
    return self;    
}
```

Another thing, if you are trying to switch to another tab you should try `self.activeTab = 1;` instead of `win1.close();`. 
`win1.close();` won't work if it's part of the tabs (`win1.containingTab = tab1;`). If what you want is to remove the tab, in Android, the method `removeTab` won't work neither.

Comment: From the comments in the code: // android:back and androidback have been tried

Answer (score 0):

you should use exitOnClose event for win1 only.

and also tell me which titanium ask are you using?

Comment: Titanium 3.2.0 CLI. Adding a listener for win1 only didn't work.

Comment: I reverted to Titanium 3.1.4 just to see if the 3.2 update had broken something. No joy, still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

try using "android:back" instead.